# unexpected `False` for `SymmetricMatrixQ`

Tags: core-language, tensors

Why does the following evaluate to `False`?

```
Assuming[Element[m, Matrices[{d, d}]],
 SymmetricMatrixQ[m.Transpose[m]]]  (* False *)
```

Trying tensor operations does not help much:

```
Assuming[Element[m, Matrices[{d, d}]],
 TensorSymmetry[m.TensorTranspose[m]]]  (* {} *)
```

**Edit:**

Note that despite failing on this, `TensorSymmetry` does pay some attention to `Assumptions`.  (As noted by @JohnDoty, `SymmetricMatrixQ` apparently does not.)

```
Assuming[Element[m, Matrices[{d, d}, Symmetric]],
 TensorSymmetry[m]]  (* Symmetric[{1, 2}] *)
```

Comment: Nothing I see in the documentation suggests that `SymmetricMatrixQ` uses the `Assumptions` mechanism, so to it your `m` is just a symbol, not a matrix.

Comment: @JohnDoty I expected in that case it would remain unevaluated.  But perhaps it is testing as does `MatrixQ`?  (I.e., insisting on a rectangular array.)  This still does not explain the result for `TensorySymmetry`.

Comment: @Alan The `*Q` functions will (almost) always evaluate to `True` or `False` for all arguments (so no "remain unevaluated"). Also, from the documentation of `SymmetricMatrixQ`: "`SymmetricMatrixQ[m]` gives `True` if `m` is *explicitly symmetric*, and `False` otherwise." (emphasis mine). So I think everything works exactly as intended in your example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use my `ToTensor` function (now available as a [`ResourceFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ResourceFunction)) to convert the [`Dot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot) expression into the equivalent [`TensorContract`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorContract) expression, after which [`TensorSymmetry`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorSymmetry) will return the expected result:

```
expr = M . Transpose[M];
t = ResourceFunction["ToTensor"][expr, Assumptions -> M ∈ Matrices[{d,d}]]
```

> ```
> TensorContract[M \[TensorProduct] M, {{2, 4}}]
> ```

[`TensorSymmetry`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorSymmetry) will produce the correct result now:

```
TensorSymmetry[t, Assumptions -> M ∈ Matrices[{d,d}]]
```

> Symmetric[{1, 2}]